# Save a dictionary to the DataBase with .save()

Tags: python, django

Right now I am doing this:

```
for product in request.session['productList']:
        productData = Products_model(
                Fk_Cat_id=product['cat'],
                Fk_supplier_id=product['supplier'],
                Name=product['name'],
                Price=product['price'],
                )

        productData.save()

print 'All products has been saved'
```

But maybe there is something like:

```
productData = Products_model.dictionary.(request.session['productList'])
productData.save()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can alter your dictionary so that the key names match with the names of the model parameters

```
products = [Products_model(**data) for data in request.session['productList']]
Products_model.objects.bulk_create(products)
```